# Local Storage Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to get some local storage working on my site and I am struggling.

I have several 'toggle sliders' (like these: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/#) and I would like to save the users choices to local storage so that when users return they can still see their choices from before.

I have got it working for the first toggle slider in the list however what I want to do is loop through each slider and for each one, save its 'id' and 'value' to local storage. Then once saved, on page load, recover those and alter the toggle switches depending on what it says in local storage.

Here is my code:

```
//code below saves id and value to local storage when save button is clicked
$("#button").click(function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('flip-min-1', $("#flip-min-1").val());
});
```

Ok so that works and in local storage i get the following:

```
Key: #flip-min-1    Value: yes or no depending on choice as it is a toggle slider
```

Now when browser is closed and re-opened I retreive data from local storage and use it to toggle the slider depending on what it says:

```
var storedText = window.localStorage.getItem('flip-min-1');

//if the variable in local storage is equal to yes
if(storedText = 'yes') {
    //then switch the toggle slider to the yes state so it appear in red and reads 'Attending'
    $("#flip-min-1").val(window.localStorage.getItem('flip-min-1')).keyup();
    //if the stored text is anything other than yes, the default select option will be no. By default the user is not attending any events
}
```

What i am struggling with is the fact that I have multiple toggle switches and foreach one i need to save its id and value in local storage!

I really need help, if anyone would be kind enough to put forward their time I would be greatful, thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: Compare with 1 `=` sign in your if?? Not good...

Comment: yeah, i was rushing to get this question out...

Comment: if it worked for you, you could probably mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed number of switches, simply put everything in a for loop, e.g.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#button" + i).click(function() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('flip-min-' + i, $("#flip-min-" + i).val());
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you might give all of them a class and a data attribute, like:

```
<button class="mySwitch" data-number="1">Switch 1</button>
<button class="mySwitch" data-number="2">Switch 2</button>
```

And use code like this

```
// find all switches
$(".mySwitch")
// handle click event and save
.click(function() {
  var index = $(this).attr("data-number");
  window.localStorage.setItem('flip-min-' + index, $("#flip-min-" + index).val());
});
// load all states
.each(function() {
  var index = $(this).attr("data-number");
  var storedText = window.localStorage.getItem('flip-min-' + index);

  //if the variable in local storage is equal to yes
  if(storedText = 'yes') {
      //then switch the toggle slider to the yes state so it appear in red and reads 'Attending'
      $("#flip-min-1").val(window.localStorage.getItem('flip-min-' + index)).keyup();
      //if the stored text is anything other than yes, the default select option will be no. By default the user is not attending any events
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the reply, dont have much time now but it looks to me like I will need to use your second solution. I will give it a go soon and let you know how I get on thanks!